# How to Extract xmltype as xml in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, xmltype, extract-value

I am trying to extract xml from the `xmltype` doc.

```
DECLARE
  xmlData         XMLType;
  sDocumentId     VARCHAR2(100);
  sFormat         VARCHAR2(100);
  cData           CLOB;
BEGIN
  xmlData := XMLType( '<main>
                      <document_id>1234567</document_id>
                      <format>E66</format>
                      <data><Fname>ABCD</Fname><Lname>EFGD</Lname></data>
                  </main>');

  SELECT ExtractValue(xmlData, '/main/document_id/text()'),
         ExtractValue(xmlData, '/main/format/text()'),
         ExtractValue(xmlData, '/main/data/text()')
  INTO sDocumentId,
       sFormat,
       cData
  FROM (SELECT xmlData  FROM DUAL);

  dbms_output.put_line(sDocumentId);
  dbms_output.put_line(sFormat);
  dbms_output.put_line(cData);
END;
```

How to get the output like this:

- DocumentId = `1234567`
- sFormat = `E66`
- cData = `<Fname>ABCD</Fname><Lname>EFGD</Lname>`

Comment: xmlData.Extract('/main/data/text()').getStringVal() gets you `<data>
  <Fname>ABCD</Fname>
  <Lname>EFGD</Lname>
</data>` close, but not close enough ;)

Comment: came up with which did get xml fragment: `Extract(xmlData, '/main/data/node()').getStringVal()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
SELECT  EXTRACTVALUE(xmlData, '/main/document_id/text()'),
    EXTRACTVALUE(xmlData, '/main/format/text()'),
    EXTRACT(xmlData, '/main/data').GetClobVal()
INTO   sDocumentId,
    sFormat,
    cData
FROM (SELECT  xmlData  FROM DUAL) t;
```

Please note, `EXTRACTVALUE` and `EXTRACT` are deprecated. However, I did not manage to use `XMLTABLE`, but this could be a starting point:

```
SELECT *
INTO   sDocumentId,
    sFormat,
    cData
FROM XMLTABLE('/main' PASSING xmlData COLUMNS 
    sDocumentId  VARCHAR2(100) PATH 'document_id/text()',
    sFormat  VARCHAR2(100) PATH 'format/text()',
    cData  VARCHAR2(1000) PATH 'data/text()');
```

Comment: In this, how can we get the clob data for 'data'? As I wanted to to use something live GetClobVal() to get it.

Comment: Can you please provide full query Including variables?

Answer (score 2):

Use the below code.

```
DECLARE
xmlData         XMLType;
sDocumentId     VARCHAR2(100);
sFormat         VARCHAR2(100);
cData           Clob;

BEGIN

xmlData := XMLType( '<main>
                <document_id>1234567</document_id>
                <format>E66</format>
                <data><Fname>ABCD</Fname><Lname>EFGD</Lname></data>
            </main>');


SELECT  ExtractValue(xmlData, '/main/document_id/text()'),
        ExtractValue(xmlData, '/main/format/text()'),
        EXTRACT(xmlData,'/main/data').getClobVal()
INTO   sDocumentId,
       sFormat,
       cData
FROM ( SELECT xmlData  FROM DUAL);


dbms_output.put_line(sDocumentId);
dbms_output.put_line(sFormat);
dbms_output.put_line(cData);

END;
```

Output will be

```
1234567
E66
<data><Fname>ABCD</Fname><Lname>EFGD</Lname></data>
```

Comment: Use EXTRACT function to extract xml value.And getClobVal() to get the value to clob variable.

Comment: How do you get this to display? Mine only says PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.